# How to change amount of RAM on the fly, in VMWare VM?

Tags: kernel, virtualization, vmware

I used to think that it is impossible to change the amount of RAM in VMWare VM with Ubuntu on the fly, without a reboot. I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.10 with 4.8 kernel and **open-vm-tools** as a guest inside my ESXi 6.0 now. VMWare recognizes open-vm-tools correctly.

But yesterday my friend demonstrated me that on his ESXi he has the ability to change RAM amount on the fly, in the range between reserved minimum and assigned top limit. He has appropriate controls active and available in the configuration interface (which I don't). His ESXi is also 6.0 but Ubuntu Server is 15.10 - I somehow missed to ask him for more details. He said that it "just worked" for him and he didn't do anything special to configure this.

What do I need to do, willing to achieve the same result in my ESXi? I really need to avoid reboot+downtime each time I need to change the amount of RAM on my server, and I need to change it periodically, depending on the distribution of load among VMs.

Will "official" VMWare Tools from ESXi CD help me? Or maybe I need to install **open-vm-tools-dkms** instead, though these are marked as "deprecated"?

Thanks in advance!
WBR,
Andrii

Comment: What EXSi Edition you have?

Comment: Host info says that ESX Server License Type is "VMware vSphere 6 Enterprise Plus" which is what the company actually purchased last year. Help->About says that this is VMware ESXi Version 6.0.0 Build 2494585

Comment: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/blogs/lowe/news/vmware-esxesxi-hot-add-ram-and-cpu-68.html

Comment: Thank you for the info! Somehow the option which allows CPU and RAM hot add were disabled in the interface of Windows ESXi control software. After some manipulations (namely stopping VMs and switching on the web interface of ESXi) it arrived back at me, and now it works as intended. Both manuals are correct: this one http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/blogs/lowe/news/vmware-esxesxi-hot-add-ram-and-cpu-68.html and this one, too http://www.unixarena.com/2014/11/dynamically-adding-memory-cpu-to-vmware-vm.html